# Accessibility on my iphone 3G ios 4.1 has no content please help

Tags: iphone

I upgraded my iphone 3G to ios 4.1 bad news is the accessibility menu on my settings has no content and i cant change my screen saver its always black everytime i choose a picture help me please

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't tried backup and restore of the device? That's a good first step in troubleshooting odd software glitches.

Comment: It most likely is some form of software issue, and might be an issue that is fixable with simply holding your power button until your phone shuts off, and then turning it back on

Comment: I tried it sir but still theres no content on my accessibility